# Are there some nice introductions to IDI, NRI, biomarker validation?

Tags: survival

Are there some nice introductions to 
 IDI (integrated discrimination improvement index), NRI (net reclassification index), multivariable likelihood ratios, Bayesian methods, biomarker validation, risk scores from multi-biomarker data? Where do they arise and how are they obtained or performed?

I guess the topics are from survival analysis. But I can't find it in some survival analysis books.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is much in the way of IDI and NRI in textbooks yet (it's still a fairly new idea).  I coauthored an applied paper a couple years ago using the methodology in this paper:

http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~tpourmohamad/performance%20of%20model.pdf

I would suggest reading the papers by Pencina on the topic since he (in my opinion) was first to really champion the idea.

Comment: The figure on p. 2499 of the above paper is exceptionally useful.  I do have a small issue with the use of data splitting for validation with those sample sizes.  One of the most important things to know is that standard tests of partial association (e.g., likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test) are the most powerful for testing whether a new marker adds information.

Comment: @Harrell Thank you for the compliment on my figure.  I agree with your comment as well. Our outcome variable was extremely rare and so we lacked the large sample sizes that we would have preferred to have.